# Bulk removal of large pool of dynamic urls from Google search console

Tags: seo, google-search-console

**Background:**

One can submit a `removal` request in the Google search console associated to one's web app.

Moreover, there's an option to provide a url pattern as well (instead of just a specific url). This allows a web master to remove multiple urls via a single entry. This is called `Remove all URLs with this prefix` in the search console.

So for instance, if a dynamic website has 10,000 urls of the sort `example.com/user/john-doe1`, `example.com/user/john-doe2`, `example.com/user/john-doe3`, .... and so one, the webmaster can use the aforementioned option to remove all 10,000 urls via simply submitting `example.com/user/` and selecting `Remove all URLs with this prefix`.

**The question:**

However, what if a dynamic website has a large pool of urls of the sort `example.com/john-doe1/profile`, `example.com/john-doe2/profile`, `example.com/john-doe3/profile`, ... and so on. How can this large pool be removed via the search console? Is there currently no way to do this in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can currently. Using `example.com/john-doe1/profile`, `example.com/john-doe2/profile` would remove all the search results inside the directory 'profile' but that something I think you're not looking for.

On the side note, may be you wanna try changing your site structure from `example.com/john-doe1/profile` to `example.com/profile/john-doe1`? and then try using the removals prefix tool for `example.com/profile/`. This way all the search results under profiles should get removed.

An interesting read
https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/53799332?hl=en